# Can ALL SCORM Compliant Quiz published share its attributes(Slide count, Slide viewed, Score)

Tags: scorm, ispring

Does iSpring presenter or any other Scorm Compliant Quiz published make available its quiz scores, slides viewed, slides count in a SCORM compliant way, which can be accessible by any other SCORM compliant quiz builder in the same manner at the Client side ***javascript*** itself or through any medium through which it can be accessed at client side.

Currently I am able to capture the Slides viewed, its count, and the quiz score from the event available in lms.js, but its specific to ISpring only.

Answer (score 0):

SCORM defines standard ways to report a lot of data. Here is a [complete list of the SCORM data model elements](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/).

Quiz scores are included in this data set (cmi.score.scaled, cmi.score.raw, cmi.score.min, cmi.score.max). Unfortunately though "slides viewed" and "slides count" are not available. SCORM is intended to be content agnostic; the internal implementation of content is a black box. Not all content has "slides" (and one would argue that the best content doesn't) so it doesn't make sense to have that as a generic data model element.

SCORM does provide a data model element that records "percent compete". The cmi.progress_measure element is a scaled value between 0-1 that indicates how far along the learner is in the content. That might be a good way to capture what you are looking for. Unfortunately however, since progress measure is new to SCORM 2004, not all authoring tools will report its value.

Answer (score 0):

SCORM Standard provides only a limited way to report viewer's achievents in a set of the following variables:

**cmi.progress_measure** (real (10,7) range (0..1), RW) Measure of the progress the learner has made toward completing the SCO

**cmi.scaled_passing_score** (real(10,7) range (-1 .. 1), RO) Scaled passing score required to master the SCO

**cmi.score._children** (scaled,raw,min,max, RO) Listing of supported data model elements

**cmi.score.scaled** (real (10,7) range (-1..1), RW) Number that reflects the performance of the learner

**cmi.score.raw** (real (10,7), RW) Number that reflects the performance of the learner relative to the range bounded by the values of min and max

**cmi.score.min** (real (10,7), RW) Minimum value in the range for the raw score

**cmi.score.max** (real (10,7), RW) Maximum value in the range for the raw score

These variables are generic and thus can be used by the variety of SCO objects. However, due to imporsonality of this generic mark, the SCOs aggregating mixed content in one unit (such as iSpring Presentations which can contain slides and quizzes) is not possible to track the detailed information - you just have a total mark.

iSpring presenter allows you to specify 'weight' of the slides and individual quizzes within the presentation when calculating the total mark.

*percent of slides viewed*

**SlidesPercent** = SlidesViewed / TotalSlides

*The percent of each quiz withing the presentation*

**QuizPercent**(i) = GatheredQuizScore(i) / MaximumScore(i)

*Calculate weighted percent (the sum of each learning course item percent multiplied to the corresponding weight)*

**WeightedPercent** = (SlidesPercent*SlidesWeight) + Sum(QuizPercent(i) * QuizWeight(i))

*Calculate total weight of the learning course (the sum of quiz weights plus weight of the slides*

**TotalWeight** = SlidesWeight + Sum(QuizWeight(i)

*Calculate normalized percent of the whole learning cours (0..1)*

**NormalizedPercent** = WeightedPercent / TotalWeight

*Calculate total score of the learning course*

**TotalScore** = NormlizedPercent * MaxScore

The total score is reported by iSpring learning content to LMS as cmi.score.raw

The normalized percent is reported to LMS as cmi.score.scaled

However due to the reasons described above it is not possible to report details to a generic SCORM-compliant LMS. The only solution is to make separate quizzes from slides.